# The simple past tense confusion (II) : Old connection, with a working exchange from the 1940s, shows or showed?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

In the following sentence:

> Old Connections, a telecommunications museum in Seattle, with a working exchange from the 1940s, **shows/showed** how telephones brought us together, but also tore us apart.

[image: show or shown]

I feel both **shows** and **showed** can be used here. But my teacher told me the standard answer was **shows**.

But is this really the case ?

BTW, this is a follow-up question to my old one [The simple past tense confusion, why use "was" instead of "is" here, "the classic 1984 was a broader critique of totalitarianism ..."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/336304/the-simple-past-tense-confusion-why-use-was-instead-of-is-here-the-classi)

Because Chinese does not have verb tense, when it comes to the case that both present tense and past tense seem to work I am always confused.

Comment: If the museum is still operating, and you can visit in the present, then 'shows is correct.

Comment: Yes now I see it but what about my other question in the other comment ?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your teacher; I would use **shows**. The sentence is talking about a museum and what it shows to anyone who visits it now. (The fact that the museum's name, *Old Connections*, is in the plural is not relevant - it is one museum.)

(Edited because the OP originally stated that the teacher said **show**.)

Comment: sorry I mean *shows*, present tense.

Comment: I am not confused with the museum name. I know "Old Connection" is the name. I am a little bit confused with the fact/words that "a working exchange from the 1940s", so should I use **shows** or **showed** for this **working exchange** ?

Comment: It is called 'Connections Museum Seattle' according to [its website](https://www.telcomhistory.org/connections-museum-seattle/). Its previous name was the 'Herbert H. Warrick Jr. Museum of Communications', and originally the 'Vintage Telephone Equipment Museum'

Comment: @Quilong The artifacts in the museum are from the past, but the museum is (in the present) showing how the introduction of telephone (in the past) brought us together.  So it is "shows" present tense, but "brought" past tense.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 - Ignore the 1940s. The museum is open **now**. If you go there today, you can see what it shows today.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 - see comments above. Museum open now. Present tense.

Comment: Kate Bunting:  Actually you _do_ agree with the OP's teacher.  "My teacher told me the standard answer was shows".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your words just gave me another example of my confusion, "the museum is showing how the introduction of telephone **brought** us together." But if we were talking about the general situation can't we say "the museum is showing how the introduction of telephone **brings** us together." ?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Good to know that! Thanks.

Comment: A museum tells us _now_ about things that happened _in the past_. The invention and spread of telephones happened a long time ago.

Comment: We could say that a history book **shows** us now (today, when we read it), how the introduction of gunpowder **changed** warfare (in the past, hundreds of years ago).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that that "showed" _could_ be a perfectly reasonable choice, if we were talking about a museum that no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

"shows" is correct.

The simplest form of the sentence is:

> Old Connections **shows** (something).

The phrase, "*a telecommunications museum in Seattle*" describes what "Old Connections" is, and "*with a working exchange from the 1940s*" gives some detail about "museum".

Reworded:

> The Seattle museum "Old Connections" **shows** us how telephones brought us together, but also tore us apart, by displaying old objects, like a 1940s telephone exchange that still works.

If you say "showed", it means the museum showed things in the past, but doesn't show things now.